# Insert Into using a WITH clause (CTE) causes a ORA-00928

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-insert, toad

I'm attempting to do an essentially very simple task, which is resulting in:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

All I'm trying to do is persist the results from `periods` into table `globalTable`.  Selecting works fine (I'm returned rows) however as soon as I replace it with the Insert I get the above error.

```
create global temporary table globalTable
(
    ids number(11)
);

with periods as
(
select cl.id uniqueId
from inv_mpan_hh_con_lines cl
left join invoice_vat_lines vl on
                 cl.invoice_id = VL.INVOICE_ID
where rownum < 4
)

--//Issue occurs at insert keyword.  If I comment it and uncomment select it works as expected//--
--select uniqueId
insert into globalTable
from periods;
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
insert into globalTable
with periods as
(
select cl.id uniqueId
from inv_mpan_hh_con_lines cl
left join invoice_vat_lines vl
  on cl.invoice_id = VL.INVOICE_ID
where rownum < 4
)
select uniqueId
  from periods;
```

`CTE` (WITH-clause) is a part of `SELECT` statement, according to the `INSERT` syntax you can either specify values or `SELECT` statement

Comment: Is there any documents around the syntax in this order?  Oracle really does confuse me at times.

Comment: @m.edmondson: that "document" is called "the manual": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55051 clearly shows that the `insert` keyword is either followed by a `values` clause or a subquery. If you click on the `subquery` link you are taken to the documentation of the `select` statement which in turn contains the `with` part. You should really try to understand those syntax diagrams, it's not that confusing.

Comment: @m.edmondson CTE is part of the `SELECT` statement, according to the `INSERT` [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2111652) you can either specify the `values` statement or the `select` statement